# how to set foreign key in function based view in django?

Tags: django, django-models

This is the error  -   Cannot assign "'question2'": "Answers.question" must be a "Question" instance.

model.py

```
def main(request, pk):
ques = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=pk)
if request.method == "POST":
    answerForm = AnswerForm(request.POST)
    if answerForm.is_valid():
        ans = answerForm.save(commit=False)
        ans.user = request.user
        ans.question = Answers(question=ques.question) # here assigning foreign key
        ans.answer = answerForm.cleaned_data.get['question_sel']
        print(answerForm.cleaned_data.get['question_sel'])
        ans.save()
        return redirect('main', pk=ques.pk)
else:
    answerForm = AnswerForm(request.POST)
return render(request, 'quiz/main.html', {'ques': ques,'answerForm':answerForm})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want `ans.question = ques` here. `ques` is the instance of the current question which will be saved to the answer.

If you want to get an answer with a specific question you would need to do `Answer.objects.get(question=ques)`, but that doesn't make sense in this context.